# Universally Accepted Private Variable Declaration Conventions

Tags: c#, oop

I'm currently refactoring some ugly code and splitting a large and overcomplicated class A into superclass A with subclasses B and C.

My question is, if I had private variables in the overcomplicated class that are only relevant to subclass B after the split, is there a universally accepted convention for where to declare these?

My options are:

```
protected variable in superclass A
pro: all variables located in central location
con: some variables in superclass unused by all subclasses

private variable in subclass B
pro: only shared variables present in superclass A (more "proper"?)
con: more complicated code management
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why exactly are you creating a "superclass". The variable should be in the class that needs it. It sounds like you are going from a bad code design to worst.  There is no "universal" convention for what you are doing.

Comment: By superclass, I mean a parent class. The original code was ugly because I slapped an entirely different use case into it due to time constraints, and now that I have time to refactor, I'd like to split the functionality properly into a parent class with virtual functions and subclasses that inherit and implement them. What's wrong with this code design? You answered my question though, thanks - variables should be in the class that need them.

Comment: Beware of inheritance. Prefer delegation.

Comment: Hmm... I understand the preference for delegation, but why the wariness of inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > My question is, if I had private variables in the overcomplicated class that are **only relevant to subclass B** after the split, is there a universally accepted convention for where to declare these?

**If they are only relevant to class B, put them in class B**.  To do anything else, detracts from the readability of the code and will cause confusion in the future.

If you would like to justify your answer to someone, you can point to [Separation of Concerns (SoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), which addresses your breaking apart classes.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense in hindsight, especially when applied to more than just two subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

@Ramhound was right:  The variable should be in the class that needs it

```
A - variables that are shared by both C and B
B - variables that belongs to B only
C - Variables that belongs to C only
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely put them in subclass B, the only reason you should put the methods in the class they both inherit from is if both will use the method, or there's a likely hood that in the near future another class will be added and will use the methods, properties, fields or in your case variables

Comment: I think you're thinking of instances and objects when you say harder to manage, because yes in that case, all the properties should be put in the class and the instances should only use the relevant variables to themselves. But when it comes to inheritance it's the opposite, put only what's needed in the class being inherited from

Comment: You got it right the first time - I was just confused by the small scale of my implementation and my rustiness. Had I thought about a larger implementation, I would have realized placing all the subclass properties in the superclass as protected properties would be a terrible idea.